# Release build Xcode8 crashes on iOS 9 device

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, testflight

I converted my application to Swift 2.3 in Xcode 8. There's no problem when running on simulator iOS 10 and iOS 9 (or debug build on physical iOS 9/10 device). Also our (large) set of automatic UI tests are running fine on iOS 10 device. But when creating an (release) IPA for iTunes/TestFlight, this version is crashing on iOS 9 immediately on startup. On iOS 10 is runs without any problem.

Logging shows me this:

...

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _sqlite3_key_v2
      Referenced from: /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/A5200093-5C37-46AD-8C16-BC873469EC6F/*.app/*
      Expected in: dyld shared cache
Oct 10 11:51:45 iPhone *[1310] <Notice>: dyld: Symbol not found: _sqlite3_key_v2
      Referenced from: /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/A5200093-5C37-46AD-8C16-BC873469EC6F/*.app/*
      Expected in: dyld shared cache
```

...

```
Oct 10 11:51:45 iPhone diagnosticd[84] <Error>: unable to find offset 0x836c5da8 in shared cache for arch 'arm64'
Oct 10 11:51:45 iPhone diagnosticd[84] <Error>: Invalid offset 2204917160 into shared cache for arch 'arm64'
```

...

Answer (score 0):

In the meanwhile I found out the issue myself. It's a very specific for my situation. It was a third party library (so be specific; JB4A-SDK) that caused the problem. Updating to the latest version fixed the problem.